# create autocomplete input lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, autocomplete

How can I create an autocomplete input text in lightning component
Please help either by suggest library or create one from scratch

I tried this:
https://gist.github.com/peterknolle/ef17727d994332a8ef6b#file-autccomplete-cmp

but it said that ' $j is not defined'

and also tried the one in lightning design system but it does not work and even its style is bad ( see image):
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/lookups/

[image]

Comment: In the first look you provided, it requires to add JQuery as a static resource. Did you add it?

Comment: yes I added jquery, but not same, I added jquery 2.2.4 because it is the one that compatible with locker service

Comment: Are you sure you imported well here? `<aura:requires 
       baseUrl="/resource/"
           scripts="{jquery:'jquery/jquery.js',jqueryui:'jqueryui/jquery-ui.js'}"
           deps="{jqueryui:['jquery']}"
          styles="{jqueryui:'jqueryui/jquery-ui.css'}"
     requiresReady="c.init"
 />`

Comment: Here is a great component from Philippe Ozil: https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-lookup-lwc. Sharing the link as it might help someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find Below link , Its small demo on auto complete on account lookup using lightning. Full source present in git hub, with guidance. This will help you.

Reference [Lookup auto complete](https://bitbucket.org/nlearner/lookup-lightning-component-slds/src/b151364b5203?at=master)

Comment: thanks, I will try .. but can I import it as unmanaged package?

Comment: Sorry i am not did Unmanaged  Package for now.

Comment: when I write letter it display error :
Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'label' of null]
Failing descriptor: {markup://ui:input}

Comment: http://www.sfdcmonkey.com/2017/01/07/custom-lookup-lightning-component/  as reference for further .

Comment: Your welcome ..

Comment: @NITHESHK link to the sfdcmonkey.com updated page: https://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/07/17/re-usable-custom-lookup/

Answer (score 1):

Another fantastic option is Philippe Ozil's [lookup component](https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-lookup).  You can also leverage `lightning:inputField` or `lightning:recordForm` to do a lookup for you as well, and then catch the value and process it on your own.

These options are laid out in [this post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005UMrQAM)